# Calling a service inside a Blazor component does not work

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a service that look like this:

```
namespace Hydra.Services
{
  public class Employee
  {
    public string url { get; set; }

    public async Task<EmployeeModel> GetEmployee(){
      // return JSON data
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to call the service inside my `Commpany` component as:

```
@page "/"

<div> @company ... </div> <!-- OK, company details are rendered --> 
<div> @Employee ... </div>  <!-- System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' -->

@code {

  company string; 
  emlpoyee string; 
  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
      // Get company details


      // HERE is the problem:
      EmployeeModel emp = new Employee();
      emp.url = "http://google.com";
      emlpoyee = await emp.Employee(); 
    }
  }
}
```

So, the logic to show the company works without any issue, the Employee service I am calling inside using() doesn't seem to
work. I don't know what the issue is other than the error.

This is not a problem about forgetting to include models or injecting services.

I am just a beginner so the issue is simpler than that

Comment: This code doesn't look sufficient to really show the problem.

Comment: "_I don't know what the issue is other than the error._" We don't even know what the error is, as you didn't include it.

Comment: You need to show what service you've injected into your view. Chances are its missing the reference to Employee

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel The error is included `@Employee` throws `... </div>  <!-- System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' -->`

Comment: I am injecting the `Employee` service, @mathis1337

Comment: So it looks like your service is returning `null`. Put a breakpoint inside it and see what happens. We can't tell you, as you didn't include the code.

Comment: @vaeon you did not show any injected services in your code. So we have no way of seeing any of this. You need to provide more code for hopes of help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I didn't know it could be another issue. I thought maybe I was calling the variable `@Employee` wrong so I decided to share only thaat

Comment: Oh you are calling it wrong. I'll post answer below.

Comment: How does this even compile? You've declared `emp` as an `EmployeeModel`, but then you're initializing it as an instance of the `Employee` class.

Comment: I think I made a mistake by not sharing the code I had, instead of writing a new code in the answer. Anyway, I created a new project and included the code that is showing me an error in another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74693059/variable-not-assigned-to-result-fetch-from-url-in-c-sharp-blazor) if you want to take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codes have not performed the service injection correctly as it should. I present to you the method that I use and it works correctly, I hope it will be useful.

First, you need to create an interface for your service:

```
namespace Hydra.Services
{
    public interface IEmployee
    {
        Task<EmployeeModel> GetEmployee();
    }
}
```

Then, you need to modify your service by inheriting from the interface as shown below:

```
namespace Hydra.Services
{
    public class Employee:IEmployee
    {
        public async Task<EmployeeModel> GetEmployee()
        {
            // return JSON data
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you should inject the service in `Startup.cs` or `Program.cs` as follows:

```
services.AddScoped<IEmployee,Employee>();
```

Finally, you should inject your service in the desired component as shown below and use it easily:

```
@page "/"
@using Hydra.Services
@inherits OwningComponentBase<IEmployee>

<div> @company ... </div> <!-- OK, company details are rendered --> 
<div> @Employee ... </div>  <!-- System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' -->

@code {

    private string company; 
    private EmployeeModel emlpoyee = new EmployeeModel; 

    private IEmployee employeeService => Service;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    
    // Get company details


    // HERE is the problem:
        EmployeeModel emp = new EmployeeModel();
        emp.url = "http://google.com";
        emlpoyee = await employeeService.GetEmployee(); 
    
}
```

Of course, your code has many structural problems and you probably just wanted to specify the problem in the form of an example code, so I just tried to explain the working method with your own codes so that the example is more concrete for you.

Comment: Hello, accepted the answer but it didn't work for me. I realized this happened because I didn't share the original code, so now I created another question showing all the files wth no edits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74693059/variable-not-assigned-to-result-fetch-from-url-in-c-sharp-blazor if you want to take a look, that would be nice

Answer (score 2):

You created the variable:

```
@emlpoyee
```

but you are calling `@Employee` which is going to be null.

Try switching to the variable you actually put the employee into which is:

```
@emlpoyee
```

Also I think you spelt the variable wrong. I think you meant @employee perhaps.

You populate everything here:

```
emlpoyee = await emp.Employee();
```

so calling @emlpoyee is what makes sense from the code you've provided.

So change `<div> @Employee ... </div>` to `<div> @emlpoyee ... </div>`

Comment: It would appear you are indeed calling a null variable and not the one you are dumping your info into.

Comment: It wansn't a typo, I just had made a mistake or not including the actual code. I created (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74693059/variable-not-assigned-to-result-fetch-from-url-in-c-sharp-blazor) another question where I should all the code, if you want to contribute