# Blazor No Service for type has been registered

Tags: c#, html, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am creating a blazor server app.  I keep getting "Error: System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'CompentencyProject5.Data.CustomerServices' has been registered." when trying to go to my "Fetchdata" webpage.  The error is at "customers = await @Service..."

```
@code
    {
        [CascadingParameter]
        private
        Task<AuthenticationState>? authenticationStateTask{ get; set; }
        List<CompentencyProject5Users> customers = new List<CompentencyProject5Users>();
        private string UserIdentityName = "";
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            if (authenticationStateTask !=null)
            {
                var user = (await authenticationStateTask).User;
    
                if (user.Identity !=null)
                {
                    UserIdentityName = user.Identity.Name ?? "";
                }
            }
            customers = await @Service.getCustomersAsync(UserIdentityName);
        }
    }



using CompentencyProject5.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace CompentencyProject5.Data
{
    public class CustomerServices
    {
        private readonly CompentencyProject5DataBaseContext _context;
        public CustomerServices(CompentencyProject5DataBaseContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        //Checking current user by e-mail, might need to switch that up if it doesn't work
        public async Task<List<CompentencyProject5Users>> getCustomersAsync(string currentUser)
        {
            return await _context.CompentencyProject5Users.Where(x => x.Email == currentUser).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}



// <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated by EF Core Power Tools. </auto-generated>
#nullable disable
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CompentencyProject5.Data
{
    public partial class CompentencyProject5Users
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Investments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the DI code in the startup.cs or program.cs?

Comment: I think it's an answer to your question.https://stackoverflow.com/a/74683909/4444757