# Variable not assigned to result fetch from URL in C#

Tags: c#, blazor

I have been having this problem for some time so to reproduce the error I created a new Blazor project to show you all the files.

This is my `index.razor` file:

```
@using BlazorApp1.Models.TestSuiteModel; 
@inject BlazorApp1.Services.TestSuiteService TestSuiteServ; 
@page "/"


<b> 

    @TestSuitesResult.count; 

</b>



@code {

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        this.GetTestSuites(); 
    }


    TestSuiteModel TestSuitesResult;
    protected async Task GetTestSuites()
    {
        TestSuiteServ.url = "https://dev.azure.com/****/_apis/test/Plans/12/suites?api-version=5.0";
        TestSuiteServ.PersonalAccessToken = "****";
        TestSuitesResult = await TestSuiteServ.GetTestSuites();
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

    }

}
```

The problem is `@TestSuitesResult.count;` is always null and throws this error:
[image]

Below is my Model

```
namespace BlazorApp1.Models.TestSuiteModel
{
    public class TestSuiteModel
    {
        public List<Value> value { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
    }
 // .. mode classes
}
```

Below is my Service

```
using BlazorApp1.Models.TestSuiteModel;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace BlazorApp1.Services
{
    public class TestSuiteService
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string PersonalAccessToken { get; set; }
        TestSuiteModel result;

        public async Task<TestSuiteModel> GetTestSuites()
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                // accept response as JSON
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")
                );

                // add DevOps token to the HTTP Header request
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                    "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(
                        System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                            string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", PersonalAccessToken)
                        )
                    )
                );


                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestSuiteModel>(responseData);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is the only thing I have in this project. I didn't modify or delete any file from the default Blazor project except registering the service in `program.cs`

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<TestSuiteService>(); <!-- my service -->

var app = builder.Build();
```

Also Newtonsoft is added so it could not be a missing library.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: In addition to the await problem highlighted in the answer, `TestSuitesResult` can be null yet you don't check for a null value before trying to display it.  A recipe for trouble! Do you have Nullable enabled?  You should be getting warnings.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis This was just quick demo project I created, normall I do check for null

Comment: move `@page` to the top of the document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GetTestSuites` is never awaited

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

    this.GetTestSuites(); 
}
```

It should be :

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

    await this.GetTestSuites(); 
}
```

Right now `OnInitializedAsync` completes and the page is rendered before `GetTestSuites` has a chance to complete.

There are other problems with `TestSuiteService` too. HttpClient is meant to be reused, not defined in a `using` block. Especially in Blazor, the HttpClient instance is provided by the browser. The entire `GetTestSuites` method could be replaced with a single `await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<TestSuiteModel>(url);`, where `_httpClient` can be an HttpClient registered through `AddHttpClient`. Everything else is the default behavior of [GetFromJsonAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.getfromjsonasync?view=net-7.0):

```
public interface ITestSuiteService
{
    Task<TestSuiteModel> GetTestSuites(string url);
}

public class TestSuiteService:ITestSuiteService
{
    public TestSuiteService(HttpClient client)
    {
        _httpClient=client;
    }

    public async Task<TestSuiteModel> GetTestSuites(string url)
    {
        var model=await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<TestSuiteModel>(url);
        return model;
    }
}
```

This service can be registered as a typed HttpClient :

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<ITestSuiteService,TestSuiteService>(client=>{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        $":{PersonalAccessToken}")
                    )
                )
            );
});
```

At this point the token can be retrieved from Configuration.

Another option is to use `GetAsyn`, inspect the response and use [HttpContent.ReadFromJsonAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpcontentjsonextensions.readfromjsonasync?view=net-7.0). This avoids the cost of exceptions, especially in APIs when responses like 429 (Too Many Requests) are expected :

```
    public async Task<TestSuiteModel> GetTestSuites(string url)
    {
        var response=await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var model=await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TestSuiteModel>();
            return model;
        }
        else 
        {
        ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added `await` to the method `this.GetTestSuites();` but I still get the same error. I will add the other suggestion after I fix the issue, as they are improvements. I still get `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' TestSuitesResult was null.` error

Comment: They aren't just improvements. All that extra code *increases* the chance of error. All that code can be replaced with a single line. It's *still* possible to get a NULL if the response is empty though. Have you tried calling that URL and inspect the response?

Comment: Try creating a unit test that calls only calls that URL with `ReadAsJsonAsync`. It's a lot easier to debug just a single call instead of an entire UI page

Comment: I did as you instructed but I am getting a new error now: https://i.imgur.com/uIqH9bf.png can you please check? thanks

Comment: You need to add `using System.Net.Http.Json;`.   I'm not a great lover of `ReadAsJsonAsync`.  You get your object or a null.  No status info to provide meaningful information back to the User/UI.  The null could be no data or a bad url or not authorized, ....?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I am using `using System.Net.Http.Json;` everything else is ok to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: [Polite] The error on the screen shot "HttpClient does not contain a definition of ..."  suggests otherwise.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I just added it https://i.imgur.com/7RTMsoC.png and I still get the same error. I tried reopening VisualStudio still the same issue

Comment: You need to "inject" the instance of `HttpClient` from the Services Container as shown in @PanagiotisKanavos answer into `TestSuiteService`s constructor. public TestSuiteService(HttpClient client)
    {
        _httpClient=client;
    }

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I can't find anything about `ReadAsJsonAsync` in the Microsoft doc (I know `GetFromJsonAsync`). Where is this coming from ?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine oops, [ReadFromJsonAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpcontentjsonextensions.readfromjsonasync?view=net-7.0) is defined on the response's HttpContent so you *do* have the status code.

Comment: [GetFromJsonAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.getfromjsonasync?view=net-7.0#system-net-http-json-httpclientjsonextensions-getfromjsonasync-1(system-net-http-httpclient-system-string-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) on the other hand either throws or returns the object. You'll have to inspect the exception to see why the call failed. That's the same as calling `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`, so it's no different than the question's code

Comment: I awarded the bounty for the effort and because the bounty period was running out. But even with your code I get `JsonReaderException: '<' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 0.` It seems like the response Blazor getting is an HTML and not JSON as expected. My guess is the auth is not sent or sent properly. Are you sure your code sends the auth with every request? @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 5):

The initial state of your object is null.

You have do do a null check here or provide a default object. You have three ways to fix this.
1: Check for null using if

```
<b> 
@if(TestSuitesResult is not null)
{
    @TestSuitesResult.count; 
}
</b>
```

2: Check for null using the Elvis operator

```
<b> 
    @TestSuitesResult?.count; 
</b>
```

3: Provide a default value

```
TestSuiteModel TestSuitesResult = new TestSuiteModel();
```

Also make sure to await your function in `OnInitializedAsync` otherwise you are calling your function and forgetting it.

Answer (score 2):

In blazor 6 you should always check if your object value is null, because the page is ALWAYS prerendered before the lyfeevents execute.
Is the only way.
Is not a problem of your applicattion , is just a Blazor bug.

This error is being solved in .net7 with @bind-after new tag.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-7-preview-7/